# Verilog Timing Analysis for Fixed inputs

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I have a simple piece of Verilog code where i fix two numbers. 45 and 46. Multiply them and show the output. I wrote a simple piece of Verilog code to do that. 
 
However, when I Generate the Post-Synthesis Simulation Model, the Synthesis report does not show any Timing Analysis. However, when the variables are inputs, it finds the logic and routing time for the circuit.

I am interested in these metrics for a circuit created for fixed inputs.

This is my code:

```
module SimpleMult(
    outProd
     );
    reg signed[7:0] mult1;
    reg signed[7:0] mult2;
   output reg signed[15:0]outProd;
    initial begin
     mult1 = 45;
     mult2 = 46;
    end

    always@(*) begin
    outProd = mult1 * mult2;
    end
endmodule
```

Is there anyway I can get the timing analysis to work for this?

Comment: I think that the best approximation you can get (without analog simulation) may be obtained if you find a way to restrict (during STA) the analyzed values of your inputs (which you should define) to 0,0 and 45,46. Though, I don't know whether STA tools support this functionality.

Comment: What tools are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you face here is that the multiplication of constants is a constant and therefore has no timing.

A method to measure the timing would be to synthesise the multiplier with 2 inputs. Then perform a gate level sim including the SDF timing information. Taking both inputs from 0, to the fixed values. In a waveform editor you should be able to see ripple on the output of the multiplier. Measure the time from new input to settled output.

Remembering that Silicon timing is quite variable, You might get fast or slow (or centred) Silicon. Temperature will also effect the timings. You will need to run the sim with at least two corners Max and Min. Resulting in a max and min time to transition from (0 input to) fixed input to stable result.

Also realise that the timing used in this method is from 0, it will be different with different starting conditions.

You could try having two LUTs (Look Up Tables) holding the input values 0 and your fixed ones and see what your synth tool does. Likely will optimise to a LUT with 0 and the answer.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to define instantaneous transition on input ports only (is using the term "zero-delay" appropriate for this?)? Otherwise, what precautions should be taken in order to minimize the impact of input delay?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov Timing analysis is not my area of expertise a new question may get a better response. With that in mind it is not clear if you are referring to simulation/investigating behaviour or real timing for a synthesised netlist targeting hardware? I would expect Inputs driven from a testbench to be instant.

Comment: "I would expect Inputs driven from a testbench to be instant" - this is the answer I've been looking for. I'm not familiar with GLS, and form a brief review of a few papers on the web I couldn't understand whether one can control the timing of the test vectors.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be inputs to have any time analysis.

The synthesizer knows `mult1` and `mult2` are constants. Since `outProd` is only depended on constants, `outProd` will be optimized to a constant. Constants have no timing information.

Comment: I understand. However, I wish to find the total time taken by the module to compute the product of 2 specific numbers. 
If I let mult1 and mult2 be inputs, it would compute the maximum combinational path and give me a generalized timing analysis for a 8x8 bit multiplier. 
Any ideas or suggestions as to how I would go about this?

Comment: @PrashantVaidyanathan What would be the time points to measure? At any given time, including time 0, the values will be the same. Make only one value as a constant and the other an input (or only certain bits as inputs or constants) will limit possible range but cannot limit it to exclusively `45*46`. You could try assigning the static values to initial as `8'hx` then `#0` before assigning to 45 and 46. The synthesizer will either gives errors or optimize it out. Using an analog simulator and ramping the the supply voltage can give you some timing, but as a function the ramp rate.